# Add Textbox TemplateField Column To GridView Programmatically

Tags: asp.net

How do I add a TextBox column to a GridView from code behind?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx#aspnett12ustmpfldsvb_topic3) and add a TextBox to the ItemTemplate/EditItemTemplate.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
```

You can bind it on the aspx as in the example above or in GridView.RowDataBound:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    Select Case e.Row.RowType
        Case DataControlRowType.DataRow
            Dim dr As DataRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row)
            Dim TxtFirstName As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("TxtFirstName"), TextBox )
            TxtFirstName.Text = dr("FirstName").ToString
    End Select
End Sub
```

Edit: Here is a simple example on how to add a TemplateField dynamically:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim txtColumn As New TemplateField
        txtColumn.ItemTemplate = New TextColumn
        Me.GridView1.Columns.Add(txtColumn)
    End If
End Sub

Class TextColumn
    Implements ITemplate

    Public Sub InstantiateIn(ByVal container As System.Web.UI.Control) Implements System.Web.UI.ITemplate.InstantiateIn
        Dim txt As New TextBox
        txt.ID = "MyTextBox"
        container.Controls.Add(txt)
    End Sub
End Class
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.templatefield.aspx

Comment: @Raika: Sorry, i've read over this part ;) As a first start have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.templatefield.aspx

Comment: i want somthing like this : **TemplateField tmp = new TemplateField(); tmp.Add(textbox); grd.Columns.Add(tmp);**