# Read a dynamically created textbox in a Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, .net-4.0

I am dynamically adding a textbox to certain rows (one column only) of a gridview.  I add the controls with this insdie of a test condition (works fine):

```
        TextBox txtASIN = new TextBox();
        txtASIN.ID = "TxtASIN" + e.Row.RowIndex;
        e.Row.Cells[4].Controls.Add(txtASIN);
        int i = e.Row.Cells[4].Controls.Count; //TEST: This returns 1 correctly
```

I want the user to be able to enter values into one or more of these textboxes and then update the database with a single button click (not one click for each row).  The problem I'm having is how to access those values on a button click event.  I did a simple test this way to try to see the value in the second row but get null in temp1 (I am certain there is a value entered in that textbox):

```
    protected void btnUpdate1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox temp = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[1].FindControl("txt1");
        string temp1 = temp.Text;
        int i = GridView2.Row.Cells[4].Controls.Count; //TEST: This returns 0 incorrectly        }
```

Once I can make this work, I can iterate through the rows and do what I need to do with the values.  I don't know if the text entered in the textbox is actually readable without a postback but I'm otherwise stumped.  Open to better suggestions on how to do this.

Thanks.

EDIT:  Here is where I am now.  I can see the textboxes in my column fine.  I put a break in on a button that attempts to read them and this is what I'm seeing.  If I check GridView2.Rows[0].Controls.Count, I get 8, which is the correect number of columns.  If I check GridVeiw2.Rows[0].Cells[4].Controls.Count, I get 0, which is wrong because the textbox is there.  I can get a Count of 1 right after I dynamically create it but not when I perform a subsequent button click.

Can anyone explain this?  I feel if I can get past this holdup, I can get the rest done.

Thanks again.

Comment: Note that you have to recreate the controls on every postback. ASP.NET will not remember it for you.

Comment: A .NET 4.0 application could just as easily be ASP.NET as WinForms or WPF or Silverlight.  The tag you used wasn't specific enough.

Comment: Sorry Roman...wasn't thinking along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign an ID to the TextBox controls and then access them by that ID in FindControl(). Also, make sure you're adding the controls in the Page's Init() method of the life-cycle. That way it gets added to ViewState.

```
TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
txt1.ID = "txt1"; 
e.Row.Cells[4].Controls.Add(txt1);
```

EDIT: I just remembered another possible solution. Instead of programatically creating the TextBox controls in the code-behind just create a TemplateField in the GridView.

[Add Textbox TemplateField Column To GridView Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702536/add-textbox-templatefield-column-to-gridview-programmatically)

Comment: Makes perfect sense but still didn't change the result.  (Have to run out for a bit but will check back ASAP)

Comment: Ok, added something else that you may need as well depending on where you're executing the code to instantiate the TextBox controls.

Comment: Not sure what you added.  was it the comment about adding the controls in the Init() method?  I'm adding them in the RowDataBound method of the gridview.  Is that a problem?

Comment: @nycdan Yes, that was the suggestion but it may not be feasible since it looks like you depend on the grid being data bound which it isn't yet at that point (Init()). You can also get the TextBox values on the PostBack in the Request.Form collection.

Comment: Is this similar to what Decker is saying about putting the textboxes in the html?

Comment: Not really, you can leave the TextBox's how they are. Just set the ID for them and then on the PostBack look at the Request.Form collection and you can lookup the TextBox values by their ID's. E.g. string text = Request.Form["txt1"];

Comment: George,  I must be doing something wrong.  Every attempt to access the control in debug mode returns null.  I have even tried accessing a known Label control and get null as well.  Is this not possible?

Comment: Added more info to original post.  Basically I can see a controls.count of 8 in the gridview row, but when i look at the cell that contains the textbox, I see a controls.count of 0.

Comment: I think you will not be able to programmatically access the TextBox controls because of the reason stated in comment #7 (No ViewState). Try my suggestion in comment #9 using Request.Form["ControlID"] to access the values from the TextBox controls.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a different approach, putting the text box in the html markup of the page and then control the visible or readonly property of it on the ItemDataBound event.  That way, the control will always be there and you don't have to worry about the lifecycle stuff.

Comment: when i don't show the textbox, it is because i have a value in that cell i want to show instead.  Will that invalidate this approach or can it work both ways?

Comment: It should still work, but what if you want to show the value and have the textbox at the same time?  Watch the formatting.

Comment: Don't need to show both.  I either show the value, or if there is none, I show the textbox.  I will try this....Thanks.